# ¿Cómo reproducir DVD/CD Rom usando el directorio?

Tags: c#, windows

Estoy tratando de dar

```
Process.Start(@"D:\", "windows media player")
```

Pero sucede que sólo abre la carpeta del DVD, pero no quería que sucediera eso, quiero que abra con un programa. Ex Windows Media Player

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Lee el archivo `autorun.inf` en la raíz del disco

Lee el valor del key `open` y ahí estará la ruta del archivo que debes lanzar usando `Process.Start()`

Si quieres la documentación completa de ese archivo se encuentra aquí: [Autorun.inf Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/autorun-cmds#open)

Comment: En mi disco no tiene autorun.inf

Comment: Entonces que es lo que esperas ejecutar? Se trata de un DVD de video? Que proceso esperas iniciar al ejecutar tu código?

Comment: Es un dvd / cd quiero reproducir ambos a través de código, cuando usted da un clic en el dvd automáticamente se abre con un programa. Es prácticamente eso, cuando ejecuto la línea de código quiero que abra la letra del disco con un programa, puede ser el Windows Media Player

Comment: Entonces pasale la ruta del proceso que quieras ejecutar con los parámetros correctos para reproducir el DVD

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar qué proceso deseas iniciar, o sea, el archivo ejecutable:

> Process.Start("E:\elprograma.exe")